# Углубление в terrain

Tags: unity3d, 3d

Как сделать углубление в terrain?

Comment: Может не в тему, но я бы посоветовал terrain лучше делать в 3d max или cinema4d

Comment: @ИльяСтепцов не стоит удалять вопрос после получения ответа. Если он помог - можно отметить его галочкой

Answer (score 4):

В теории так:

- У террейна (Terrain) на второй вкладке (Paint height) есть поле `Height`. Нужно установить его в какое-то начальное значение и нажать `Flattern`

  **Важно (!):** при нажатии `Flattern` все, что уже было создано на местности - сплющится, пропадет. Так что это нужно делать **до** того, как что-то "рисовать" на террейне.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Теперь на первой вкладке (Raise/Lower terrain) можно выбрать любую кисть и удерживая <kbd>Shift</kbd> вазякать мышкой

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]