# Оставить следы. Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

у меня, при разработке игры на unity 3d, возник вопрос, как при падении объекта и далее столкновением с другим объектом оставались следы.

Что мне именно нужно: летит куб и сталкивается с платформой и остаётся на их месте столкновения след, но куб с кубом(однородные объекты) не образовывают следа.

Comment: Столкновение объектов можно реализовать через [Коллайдеры](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html). А вот насчет самого углубления... Тут зависит от того, как вы хотите это реализовать и как вообще вы хотите, чтобы это выглядело. Вот например нашел про углубление в terrain: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703555/%D0%A3%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-terrain. Думаю, подобный запрос даст нужные результаты: `deepening in terrain unity` (`углубление в terrain unity`)

Answer (score -2):

Collision, TryGetComponent, Instantiate - это ваше решение.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Человек ничему не научится, если ему подсказывать что и как делать... Я направил его. Это информации вполне хватит для решения задачи. Алгоритм очень легкий. Не более 30 строк кода.

Comment: @АлексейМорозов Суть StackOverflow не в том, чтобы научить кого-либо что-либо делать, а в том, чтобы сформировать базу вопросов и ответов, в которую в будущем каждый может зайти и воспользоваться знаниями. Если вы внимательно прочитаете статью [Как дать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), то узнаете, что ответ-ссылка - это плохой ответ, если в нем подробно не объясняется что нужно делать. А у вас даже ссылки нет. Не хотите прописывать эти 30 строк кода—вы можете описать общий алгоритм или хотя бы объяснить как указанные функции стоит использовать (а то заминусуют)